# AVSpeechUtterance at internal when App in Background

Tags: swift

I've been searching high and low but can't seem to land on a viable solution.  What would be the best design for an IOS timer app that utilizes AVSpeechUtterance for "Text-to-Speech".  The app should speak text at a set interval as the timer ticks down when app is in both background/foreground.

I have the app working in the foreground using Timer + AVSpeechUtterance however once the app goes to the background everything will stop.  I realize I need to update the timer upon the app reEntering the foreground using a saved variable however I can't seem find a way to trigger AVSpeechUtterance while the app is in the background (Ex: 10 minute countdown, app should speak every minute regardless of foreground/background).

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app actually run in the background? How?

Comment: No - the app does not run in the background at all.  Though I've seen apps with a similar approach, for example: Workout apps like HIIT timers which allow a countdown that speaking while in the background.  How is this being done?

Comment: Well first the app needs to run in the background. That requires special arrangements. It's been explained many times here already.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture" background mode?

Comment: In part yes, but there is more to it than that. You have to be _doing_ something that keeps the app going in the background.

Comment: It would appear the best option is to play silence via the AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this was to play a silent mp3 with AVAudioPlayer.  With the "Audio, AirPlay and Picture" background mode, the AVAudioPlayer allows the app to run in the background.  When the workout is complete, I stop the AVAudioPlayer.